# How many bomb attacks does my 8th-level Bomber Alchemist get with a Full Attack?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, alchemist

I was wondering what a full attack would look like for a level 8 alchemist. I've seen a few builds, but i must be missing something because the BAB For my full attack using bombs doesn't match and all the builds vary too.

So again my question is what would a full attack (5 bombs? Or would it be 4?) for a level 8 look like?

Relevant PC details:

- Current BAB +6/+1
- Dex w/Dex mutagen +6
- Point blank shot +1
- Throw anything +1

With the fast bombs discovery, rapid shot(−2) and two weapon fighting (−2) feats i would be able To throw five (?) bombs in total.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but as far as I can see, an Alchemist's bomb is not a light weapon. This makes the two-weapon fighting penalty -4.

Answer (score 2):

The [official FAQ](http://paizo.com/paizo/faq/v5748nruor1fn#v5748eaic9n8l) says that those feats work with bombs.

> **Alchemist: If an alchemist has the Fast bombs discovery, can he use Rapid Shot, Two-Weapon Fighting, Improved Two-Weapon Fighting, haste, and similar abilities and effects to add more attacks?**
>
> As written, yes, all of these apply because fast bombs "functions just like a full-attack with a ranged weapon."

Yes you should be able to throw 5 bombs: 2 from BAB, 1 from Rapid shot, 2 from both two weapon fighting feats.

Comment: What are the to-hit modifiers? I get +10/+10/+10/+5/+5 at point blank range, does that look right?

Comment: I think you are right. Wondering if rapid shot takes the -2 from two weapon fighting

Comment: @gitmach They do. Rapid shot affects all your attacks, and so does two-weapon fighting. The only question is whether a bomb is a light weapon, which I can't seem to find in the rules. If not, it's +8/+8/+8/+3/+3

Comment: @gitmach On another note, here on SE we like to see the content of a link reproduced in the answer, if possible, in case the link ever goes dead. While it might seem unlikely for the FAQ to go down completely, remember that paizo might reorganize their site at some point in the future, which can invalidate the link.

Comment: Bombs are thrown weapons, and per default, if not listed, all weapons are one-handed weapons (or GM fiat). The penalties should be -4, but most builds ignore that, due to the size of "a bomb" and it having no considerable weight listed, and thus consider only a -2 penalty.
I would also consider it a -2 penalty.
But i dont think i would let thrown weapons work with rapid shot, the feat says clearly "ranged weapons", and we have three typés of weapons, melee, ranged and thrown. I would probably make a NEW feat that works only for thrown weapons.

Comment: Then again, anything that has a range can be treated as a *ranged weapon*, so it should be legit by RaW.

Comment: @MrLemon I will keep that in mind